# Using python to read multiple word documents and output findings to excel in order of importance

Tags: python, scripting

I have recently started in Marketing and I would like to automate the sorting of word documents in order of importance.  This will be a monthly task and I would like to use python if possible.

I have 500 word documents that I want to sort into order of importance.  This will be based on certain keywords in the document (ie HIGH) and then a on number within the document 0 - 1000. So the highest number gets priority after 'HIGH'.

There is also a title of the word documents which are all different.

I would like the output into an excel file or some other medium so that I can see which documents should take priority.  This can be based on the title of the document.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I see a question here. What is it you're looking for?

Comment: Hello! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is likely too broad. Stackoverflow is no a free coding service. Try to implement your script and if you encounter difficulties in a specific point, come back.

Comment: .....Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: I would like to know 1. Is it possible and 2. Will it be possible for someone who is relatively new to Python

Comment: Yes, it's all possible as far as I can see. The tricky bit would be calculating the importance, I think - that's not a very detailed specification!

Comment: So python would be able to read the MED within the document and output to a file? This could be run as a batch of around 500 documents? Inqqi

Comment: 500 documents received.
Run a python script to look at the content of each document.  
Any document with 'MED' within it the output is listed using the document name either to an excel document or some other format.
The documents are then dealt with in order of the list by staff.